# Test dotnet dll for entrypoint

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a script I'm building, and need to quickly test if a dotnet dll has an entrypoint. I know this can be done via reflection, but I'm wondering if there is a lightweight way of determining that externally?

So kind of `dotnet MaybeALibrararyOrExecutable.dll`, but without actually running it, if that makes sense.

Does this exist?

Comment: A dll will always have an entry point. Did you mean to ask if the dll, when referenced from a .NET solution, makes certain types available?

Comment: As in, is this .NET Core / .NET 5 and up assembly runnable? Using dotnet as the host

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867810/11683?

Comment: I can build this already using C#, I'm looking for an existing external way of achieving this (which may not exist) from a script.

Comment: You can call the `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName` from PowerShell just as well?

Comment: This smells like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if there is a `_CorExeMain` string in the DLL.

On Windows - `findstr /c:"_CorExeMain" .\filename.dll`

Comment: So a text file containing `_CorExeMain` will pass.

Comment: Thanks Vishvaka, this is exactly what I was looking for. On macOS/Linux I can do `grep "_CorExeMain" .\filename.dll`

Comment: @Stuart If *that* is all you need, then it would be easier to conclude it's a valid dll because it ends with `.dll`.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood @GSerg, a dotnet program that is running will end in .dll, and a dotnet library will also end in .dll, only one of them is runnable, that is what I want to check. And I'm doing it from ansible, so ideally a crude unix command is what I'm after.

Comment: @Stuart Well, from your [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221891/test-dotnet-dll-for-entrypoint/69222101?noredirect=1#comment122347198_69221891) it looked like you are trying to determine if this dll-named file is a valid dll, structure wise and such. Clearly you used a different definition of "runnable".

Comment: Language is hard, I felt if I over communicated the *precise* requirements of the question, acceptance criteria if you will, it would be a difficult question to engage with. I think I got the balance right here, and anyway, some people understood it enough to provide the answer I was looking for. I'm thick skinned, but for newcomers this question nic-picking is not something they should be subjected to, can I ask you to dial it down please.

Comment: @Stuart Yes, you can ask me to make allowance for new users and let them produce poor answers, and only hold the old timers to the higher standard of quality. And I will kindly decline your request because, while no one is going after anyone's feelings here, putting said feelings before the correctness of one's content is not acceptable. (Note that this entire argument is not even applicable here as this user, according to the profile, has been a member for 2 years and 8 months.) It's fine that you got your answer, it's just that it may not make much sense for future readers, as written.